# Chosing a small microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, pic, avr, embedded, msp430

My IO/peripheral requirements are extremely minimal (I2C, a timer output, 2-3 GPIO). Problem is, I'm not sure how much "compute" I need, especially since there's not a lot of straightforward metrics for "compute power" (comparing clock speed is only relevant within the same architecture from my understanding). My do-data will be doing a very light amount of DSP (basically, a simple filter and time derivative @ 120-ish hz).

I'm tempted to go with an AVR, since it's familiar territory, but I feel like the ATMega328p is overkill; but of ATMega, ATTiny, or similar PIC, STM8, MSP430, etc, I'm not sure how to narrow my search. Almost everything meets the IO requirements, but besides that I'm not sure how much memory, processing power etc I'll need.

Comment: They are all comparable. Like agonizing over generic sedan 1 2 or 3. Pick the one that piques your fancy.

Comment: usually I narrow the search by availability, and sort by price

Comment: You've outlined your predicament, but forgotten to ask a question. While you think of what question to ask, remember that here (like most other SE sites) [shopping](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) is off-topic.

Comment: "Filter + time-derivative" isn't enough on its own to determine necessary compute power. What is your filter order?

Comment: I don't think overkill really matters for one-offs because you can just re-use the same libraries and configuration you write for a bigger project in the future, as long as you can handle the complexity of that bigger MCU. Pick the processor you can find and afford the IDE and debugger/USB in-circuit programmer for and the MCU line that will support futures projects so you can re-use code.

Comment: If you yourself don't know what performance you need, and what budget you have, and how much area the circuit should take at max, how much power consumption you can afford, then how will we ever know? Closing.

Comment: Nick, start with a crafted software design for us. How often does the CPU wake up? If you have inputs (ADC, for example) what's the exact spacing between sampling? For output (DAC for example, or?) what's the exact spacing between output updates? What other work must be done in between, for what reason (offset measurement?), and what are all of the processing steps I need to take? What's your power budget? When I design an instrument, I have all of this mapped out very well. I could provide a real example, in fact. Once you know this stuff, the selection is actually fairly easy.

Comment: Why are you only considering 1990s technologies? Use a Cortex M0, it is cheaper than all those old legacy options because of time to market and less 8-bit related bugs. It's far more future-proof than those dying architectures. Less current consumption and obviously far more powerful than you need.

Comment: @Lundin I’m genuinely curious to know your thoughts on the above suggestions: are they all based around a dying architecture? Surely PICs released this year have an improved architecture over that of 30 years ago?

Comment: @ezra_vdj My thoughts are this: [8-bit MCU roadmap](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b9/2e/1f/b92e1f22a447fd963a1bed121348781f.jpg). Doesn't matter if it's PIC, AVR or STM8, as you can see from the linked picture there are lots of different kinds.